# Calling Java from JavaScript with Nashorn

Tags: javascript, nashorn

I have a Chrome extension project where I should make a call to Java function from my JavaScript source file. I'm trying to use Nashorn for this purpose, But in the following line:
`var MyJavaClass = Java.type('my.package.MyJavaClass');`
I'm getting the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Java is not defined

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Are you writing a Chrome extension or using Nashorn? I'm not aware of any way to make Chrome use Nashorn instead of V8.

Comment: How are you making your Chrome extension communicate with Nashorn?

Comment: `var MyJavaClass = Java.type('my.package.MyJavaClass');
var result = MyJavaClass.fun1('John Doe');
print(result); `

Comment: The example you link to shows how to use the `jjs` tool which is part of Nashorn. Your `background.js` tool is running in Chrome, not in `jjs`.

Comment: The example is not about using jjs tool.

Comment: You can look at "Invoking Java Methods from Javascript" part.

Comment: From the document you link to: "Using Nashorn
The Nashorn javascript engine can either be used programmatically from java programs or by utilizing the command line tool jjs, which is located in $JAVA_HOME/bin."

Comment: *You can look at "Invoking Java Methods from Javascript" part.* — That's part of the same article. You can (and must) imply that the title means "Invoking Java Methods from JavaScript running in Nashorn".

Comment: Please just don't reply if you can't answer or help me with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nashorn is a Java library which can be used to add support for JavaScript to a program written in Java.

It is not a feature built into the JavaScript language.

It is not a feature built into Chrome.

You cannot use Nashorn from a Chrome extension.

Chrome has no mechanism to allow JavaScript to invoke Java code.

[Chrome doesn't even support Java as a plugin](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) any more.

---

There are two basic approaches you can take to run `my.package.MyJavaClass` from Chrome:

- Rewrite `my.package.MyJavaClass` in JavaScript
- Wrap `my.package.MyJavaClass` in a web service (e.g. using a Servlet) and then access it via Ajax (`fetch` / `XMLHttpRequest`).

Comment: In that case what do these lines mean:
`var MyJavaClass = Java.type('my.package.MyJavaClass');     
var result = MyJavaClass.fun1('John Doe');     
print(result);      ` 
from the article,

Comment: That's pretty basic JavaScript syntax. The only slightly odd thing about it is the `Java` object that Nashorn provides as a global. You are using Chrome, not Nashorn, so it isn't available as a global to you.